# Why do firefox addons take several seconds to update?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I'm running on an overclocked quad-core to 3.6ghz. I've got a lot of fast ram and an SSD. My motherboard is top tier.

Yet, when my Firefox addons update, I have to sit here and wait several seconds (like 6 or 7 seconds) after they download. A big Visual Studio project loads faster than it takes the addons to update. I'm talking about even after they download, I have to wait 6-7 seconds for them to finish updating.

Is there an artificial pause in Firefox updates or something?

Comment: You can run the fastest computer in the world, you don't know what is done in this updating, it can easily be more expensive than loading your VS project. No reason for an artificial pause, it just takes that time to update, nothing to do about it, not much else to answer to that.

Comment: i don't care for 'fast ram' and 'top tier motherboards' (which is old junk next week anyway :). how about precise system specifications, the operating system and the Firefox addons you have installed?

Comment: I agree with Gnoupi. I don't think that time differs significantly between the lowest and the highest range of machines. Some things just take some time. But, why is it of any importance ? I mean, how often do they update ?

Comment: I find it a very interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Update and Uncheck the auto-update for Installed Add Ons.

Probably the best solution would be to change the [extension update interval](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Extensions.):
You can do so with extensions.update.interval .  It is set by default to 1 week (86400 seconds)

Comment: prior to firefox 1.5 the default was 1 week 604800000 in miliseconds
firefox 1.5 and above it is one DAY 86400 seconds.  My own recent experience (with komodo and not firefox) is that is is using minutes.  Buyer-beware

Answer (score 0):

I just assumed that it was DNS lookups causing the delay.

I've actually reduced the quantity of add-ons simply because of this annoyance.  Surely this could be done in the background....

Answer (score 0):

A fast computer won't get the Internet faster... Maybe the site where the extensions are stored is busy or your browser is doing checks before letting you install an update

Comment: He mentioned "after they download". So it's not the download time, only updating.